# get values of a row using a keyword

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

We have a Python dataframe, now we need to find the values by giving a Keyword, as soon as the keyword is matched the entire row needs to be extracted as a list whilist removing the NaN values from it.
 The Keyword would usually be in the first column of the dataframe
Any suggestions?
sample input[image: see this image]
sample Output: if the Keyword is "State", the output needs to be list = [State,Madhya Pradesh]

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: @Mahadevan provide a sample input and output

Comment: df[df[field_name]==Keyword_to_match].values this will give a numpy.ndarray

Comment: @dataLeo help me out on how to give the samples, as i am importing an xlsx file to the dataframe

Comment: I'm asking to put sample input/output dataframes in question.

Comment: @min2bro there are no field names, maybe index will do?

Comment: @MahadevanTyagi Give names to the dataframe columns and then apply the solution I gave above.

Comment: @min2bro it gives an empty list as the output

Comment: @min2bro I did change the column names, but still it shows an empty list

Answer (score 1):

You should follow community guidelines to post a question. However, here's a solution on a dummy dataset -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['State','City','Town'],
                  'Col2':['abc', 'random', 'defg'],
                  'Col3':['Madhya Pradesh', 'VBI', 'KJI']})

df

    Col1    Col2    Col3
0   State   abc     Madhya Pradesh
1   City    random  VBI
2   Town    defg    KJI

keyword = 'State'    <- give keyword here
vals = df[df.Col1 == keyword].Col3
vals

0    Madhya Pradesh
Name: Col3, dtype: object

lst = [keyword, vals.values[0]]
lst
['State', 'Madhya Pradesh']
```

Comment: shows error as            lst = [keyword, vals.values[0]]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: The code I've provided is meant for given dataframe `df`. Change the `lst` statement according to your data

Comment: the vals object here show "Series([], Name: c, dtype: object)" as output

Comment: I did that alreade, or else the error would have been "no object named Col1 in the dataframe df"

Comment: Thankyou so much for your effort, but the error still remains(I changed the column names accordingly) Series([], Name: Col3, dtype: object)

Comment: Really sorry for the trouble the code I developed previously is working fine !    try this location = df[(df == n).any(1)].stack()[lambda x: x != n].unique()

Answer (score 0):

keyword = 'State'

location = df[(df == keyword).any(1)].stack()[lambda x: x != keyword].unique()

location_item = location.item()

This works better!